# Combine smoothness and metallic with frag Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to add some Smoothness and Metallic to my custom shader in order to have dark texture for day/night cycle.

For the moment, i have a procedurale planet and my shader draw different textures based on height (distance between center of planet and vertex at surface).

Until there, it works !

Now I really need to add Smoothness and Metallic to material but with my shader the textures of my procedurale planet is black and dont know why ? I have a pass for frag and then a surf function for smoothness and metallic. Why this doesn't work please ?

However when I look at the material icon and I change value it looks nice but procedurale planet is always black no matter of value i change and the color i set.

Can't solve this problem since too long time. Please need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my shader :

```hlsl
 Shader "Custom/Planet" {
 Properties {
     _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
     _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
     _Tex0 ("Tex 0", 2D) = "white" {}
     _Tex1 ("Tex 1", 2D) = "white" {}
     _Tex2 ("Tex 2", 2D) = "white" {}
     _Tex3 ("Tex 3", 2D) = "white" {}
     _Tex4 ("Tex 4", 2D) = "white" {}

     _Blend0to1and1to2 ("Blend between 0 and 1, 1 and 2", Vector) = (0,1,2,3)
     _Blend2to3and3to4 ("Blend between 2 and 3, 3 and 4", Vector) = (0,1,2,3)
     _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
     _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
 }
 SubShader {
     Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
     LOD 200

     Pass
      {
         Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

         CGPROGRAM

                 #pragma vertex vert
                 #pragma fragment frag

                 #include "UnityCG.cginc"
                 #pragma target 3.0

                 sampler2D _Tex0;
                 sampler2D _Tex1;
                 sampler2D _Tex2;
                 sampler2D _Tex3;
                 sampler2D _Tex4;

                 float4 _Blend0to1and1to2;
                 float4 _Blend2to3and3to4;

                 uniform float4 _Tex0_ST;
                 uniform float4 _Tex1_ST;
                 uniform float4 _Tex2_ST;
                 uniform float4 _Tex3_ST;



                 struct appData {

                     float4 vertex : POSITION;
                     float2 uv1 : TEXCOORD0;
                     float2 uv2 : TEXCOORD1;
                     float2 uv3 : TEXCOORD2;
                     float2 uv4 : TEXCOORD3;

                 };

                 struct v2f {
                     float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                     float2 uv1 : TEXCOORD0;
                     float2 uv2 : TEXCOORD1;
                     float2 uv3 : TEXCOORD2;
                     float2 uv4 : TEXCOORD3;
                     float4 col : COLOR;

                 };
                       #define PI 3.141592653589793

                  inline float2 RadialCoords(float3 a_coords)
                  {
                      float3 a_coords_n = normalize(a_coords);
                      float lon = atan2(a_coords_n.z, a_coords_n.x);
                      float lat = acos(a_coords_n.y);
                      float2 sphereCoords = float2(lon, lat) * (1.0 / PI);
                      return float2(sphereCoords.x * 0.5 + 0.5, 1 - sphereCoords.y);

                  }
                 v2f vert (appData vInput) {
                     v2f output;
                     output.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (vInput.vertex);
                     output.uv1 = TRANSFORM_TEX(vInput.uv1, _Tex0);
                     output.uv2 = TRANSFORM_TEX(vInput.uv2, _Tex1);
                      output.uv3 = TRANSFORM_TEX(vInput.uv3, _Tex2);
                       output.uv4 = TRANSFORM_TEX(vInput.uv4, _Tex3);
                     output.col = length(vInput.vertex);
                     return output;
                 }

                  half4 frag (v2f fInput) : COLOR {

                 half4 c0 = tex2D (_Tex0, fInput.uv1);


                 half4 c1 = tex2D (_Tex1, fInput.uv2);


                 half4 c2 = tex2D (_Tex2, fInput.uv3);

                 half4 c3 = tex2D (_Tex3, fInput.uv4);
                 half4 c4 = tex2D (_Tex4, fInput.uv1);

                 if (fInput.col.x < _Blend0to1and1to2.x) {

                     return c0;
                 }
                 if (fInput.col.x > _Blend0to1and1to2.x  && fInput.col.x < _Blend0to1and1to2.y) {
                     return lerp(c0,c1,((fInput.col.x - _Blend0to1and1to2.x)/(_Blend0to1and1to2.y-_Blend0to1and1to2.x)));
                 }
                 if (fInput.col.x > _Blend0to1and1to2.y  && fInput.col.x < _Blend0to1and1to2.z) {
                     return c1;
                 }
                 if (fInput.col.x > _Blend0to1and1to2.z  && fInput.col.x < _Blend0to1and1to2.w) {
                     return lerp(c1,c2,((fInput.col.x - _Blend0to1and1to2.z)/(_Blend0to1and1to2.w-_Blend0to1and1to2.z)));
                 }
                 if (fInput.col.x > _Blend0to1and1to2.w  && fInput.col.x < _Blend2to3and3to4.x) {
                     return c2;
                 }
                 if (fInput.col.x > _Blend2to3and3to4.x  && fInput.col.x < _Blend2to3and3to4.y) {
                     return lerp(c2,c3,((fInput.col.x - _Blend2to3and3to4.x)/(_Blend2to3and3to4.y-_Blend2to3and3to4.x)));
                 }
                 if (fInput.col.x > _Blend2to3and3to4.y  && fInput.col.x < _Blend2to3and3to4.z) {
                     return c3;
                 }
                 if (fInput.col.x > _Blend2to3and3to4.z  && fInput.col.x < _Blend2to3and3to4.w) {
                     return lerp(c3,c4,((fInput.col.x - _Blend2to3and3to4.z)/(_Blend2to3and3to4.w-_Blend2to3and3to4.z)));
                 }
                 return c4;
             }

         ENDCG
      }

     CGPROGRAM
     // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
     #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

     // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
     #pragma target 3.0

     sampler2D _Tex1;

     struct Input {
         float2 uv_MainTex;
     };

     half _Glossiness;
     half _Metallic;
     fixed4 _Color;

     void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
         // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
         fixed4 c = tex2D (_Tex1, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
         o.Albedo = c.rgb;
         // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
         o.Metallic = _Metallic;
         o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
         o.Alpha = c.a;
     }
     ENDCG
 }
 FallBack "Diffuse"
```

}